# is it my server Caching my site

Tags: cache

I have one strange issue. in my website have installed wordpress, without any kind of cache plugins. but when ever i updated any css it not showing. i even edit my css inside wordpress editor mode, but still same. my editing showing properly in code mode. but not effect on website.

for testing i delete my style.css from server but i can still see my website working nice.

for testing issue i access website from different location. (i use Proxy site http://www.locabrowser.com/) but same..

after so i am not sure what's wrong it is. is that my server cache that file.

bellow is information for style.css which i got  form chrome dev tool in network section. i have no idea about those information. but i am see there say

```
Expires:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 15:30:14 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 15 Jun 2017 20:48:37 GMT
```

this mean what ?

**General**

```
Request URL:http://xxxxx.com/portfolio/wp-content/themes/xxxx/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:104.24.114.132:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers**

```
   Accept-Ranges:bytes
    Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800
    CF-Cache-Status:HIT
    CF-RAY:38719906f5fb531a-MIA
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:3418
    Content-Type:text/css
    Date:Mon, 31 Jul 2017 15:30:14 GMT
    ETag:"37a1-5942f2a5-7a564087cdd49235"
    Expires:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 15:30:14 GMT
    Last-Modified:Thu, 15 Jun 2017 20:48:37 GMT
    Server:cloudflare-nginx
    Vary:Accept-Encoding
    X-Turbo-Charged-By:LiteSpeed
```

**Request Headers**

```
GET /portfolio/wp-content/themes/xxxx/style.css HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: http://xxxxx.com/portfolio/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,bn;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
Cookie: wp-settings-1=editor%3Dhtml%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26imgsize%3Dfull%26mfold%3Do; wp-settings-time-1=1501121122; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_1686839693297accacd29bfe34d8aaa5=demo%7C1501687651%7CfG0Wp3zCR3AbNyQevhte2OEftzz2ubCJbRBBhoqkfX0%7C1085db41360313b91c4346327583044e97aa968e5cb2877832986bed2f173830; __cfduid=d9bec34d17ad3bb90c57b2844a353b7c21501120823; gadwp_wg_default_swmetric=pageviews; gadwp_wg_default_metric=locations; gadwp_wg_default_dimension=7daysAgo; wordfence_verifiedHuman=faf11d84f76bcfe0ecb4cfa6265c6137; wfvt_2192684998=597f4bfb2f441; _ga=GA1.2.1996543080.1501514418; _gid=GA1.2.170122283.1501514418; _gat=1
```

should i can with my server support.

Comment: You seem to be using cloudflare, which is caching this file (as can be seen from the `CF-Cache-Status`). If you didn't set it up, you might need to contact your server support...

Comment: thanks for find out issue. i saw it had cloudflare. i solve this issue from cloudflare. thank you so much